# align horizontally multi-word axis text label in ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have the following error_bar plot and I would like to align horizontally Latin America with Asia and Costa Rica with India in the axis-text.

### edit 1:

I'm looking for an axis text in a tabular form: that is a Region column and country column. The reason is that I have much more information to represent.

[image: error-bar_plot]

```
tg <- ToothGrowth
setDT(tg)
aa <- tg[,.(mean=mean(len),ci95=1.96*sd(len)),supp]
aa[,country:=c("India","Costa Rica")]
aa[,region:= c("Asia","Latin America")]


ggplot(aa, aes(y=paste(region,country), x=mean)) + 
    geom_errorbar(aes(xmin=mean-ci95, xmax=mean+ci95)) +
     geom_point()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this approach:

```
library(data.table)
library(datasets)
library(ggplot2)
#Code
tg <- ToothGrowth
setDT(tg)
aa <- tg[,.(mean=mean(len),ci95=1.96*sd(len)),supp]
aa[,country:=c("India","Costa Rica")]
aa[,region:= c("Asia","Latin America")]

#Plot
ggplot(aa, aes(y=paste(region,country), x=mean)) + 
  geom_errorbar(aes(xmin=mean-ci95, xmax=mean+ci95)) +
  geom_point()+
  theme(axis.text.y = element_text(angle=90,hjust=0.5))
```

Output:

[image]

**Update:**

```
#Code 2
ggplot(aa, aes(y=paste(region,'\n',country), x=mean)) + 
  geom_errorbar(aes(xmin=mean-ci95, xmax=mean+ci95)) +
  geom_point()+
  theme(axis.text.y = element_text(angle=90,hjust=0.5))
```

Output:

[image]

**Update 2:** A tabular form can be reached with `ggtext`:

```
library(data.table)
library(datasets)
library(ggplot2)
library(ggtext)
library(glue)
library(dplyr)
#Code
tg <- ToothGrowth
setDT(tg)
aa <- tg[,.(mean=mean(len),ci95=1.96*sd(len)),supp]
aa[,country:=c("India","Costa Rica")]
aa[,region:= c("Asia","Latin America")]

#Format data
aa %>% 
  mutate(color = c("#009E73", "#009E73"),
         name = glue("<i style='color:{color}'>{region}</i> ({country})")) -> aa

#Code 2
ggplot(aa, aes(y=name, x=mean)) + 
  geom_errorbar(aes(xmin=mean-ci95, xmax=mean+ci95)) +
  geom_point()+
  theme(axis.text.y = element_markdown())
```

Output:

[image]

You can difference by column using colors.

**Update 2:** You can use facets to reach something close to what you want:

```
#Code 3
ggplot(aa, aes(y=region, x=mean)) + 
  geom_errorbar(aes(xmin=mean-ci95, xmax=mean+ci95)) +
  geom_point()+
  facet_wrap(.~country,scales = 'free_y',strip.position='left',ncol = 1)+
  theme(strip.text.y.left = element_text(angle = 0))
```

Output:

[image]

And formating facets you can get this:

```
#Code 4
ggplot(aa, aes(y=region, x=mean)) + 
  geom_errorbar(aes(xmin=mean-ci95, xmax=mean+ci95)) +
  geom_point()+
  facet_wrap(.~country,scales = 'free_y',strip.position='left',ncol = 1)+
  theme(strip.text.y.left = element_text(angle = 0),
        strip.background.y = element_blank())
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the try. I really want the axis text in a tabular form. That is Region under region and Country under country.

Comment: @DJJ I have added an update. Is that what you want??

Comment: @DJJ I have added a new update! It can be an option !

Comment: @DJJ I have added a new update that is close to what you want!

Comment: @DJJ Also, I added a version without color in facets!

Comment: @DJJ I hope that helped. If you think this answer was useful, you could accept it or you could upvote. It is up to you and you encourage people to continue helping others :)